# Issue in display special characters fetched from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Using AJAX, I fetch data, and I have to dynamically append that data as rows in html table.

There are some special characters which are not being displayed in table. Though, they are currently shown if printed using 'alert' or with html tag.

Here is my code:

```
var mytext = '';
var color = "black";
for (t in events) {
    mytext += '<tr style="color:'+color+';">';
    mytext += '<td style="color:blue;"> <a onclick=\'load_iframe(' + events[t].event_id + ',"' + events[t].signature  +'");\'>';
    mytext += $('<div/>').html(events[t].signature).html();
    mytext += '</a> </td>';
    mytext += '<td>' + events[t].start_time + '</td>';
    mytext += '<td>' + events[t].end_time + '</td>';
    mytext += '</tr>';
}
$('#events_table > tbody:last').append(mytext);
```

The value of events[t].signature being shown in table is "venci\u00f3_humano".
If I print it using html/alert it shows correctly. : venció_humano

Can anybody please tell me how to fix this?

Thanks alot!

Comment: What is your browser?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put character encoding in head tag of the page.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Thanks

Comment: Was  there .But, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code working fine.

```
var mytext = '';
var color = "black";
mytext += '<tr style="color:grey;">';
mytext += '<td style="color:blue;"> <a onclick=\'load_iframe(7 ,"venci\u00f3_humano");\'>';
mytext += $('<div/>').html('venci\u00f3_humano').text();
mytext += '</a> </td>';
mytext += '</tr>';
$('#events_table').append(mytext);
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/2114/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks ! It works if I define the variable "test" like you have done.But, its still not working with my data "events[t].signature" which has been returned by AJAX. I have tried everything. The same string variable is correctly displayed on webpage. But, in table its not correct :(

Comment: Also, in some cases with special characters, even the href is not clickable!